# Vue.js + Element UI: Get "event.target" at change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I can't get the html field that fires the event in its event handler (in javascript is the `event.target`).

I've a form with:

- an input element attached to a function on change event
- a function that manages the change event

My code is like the following:

```js
var Main = {
    methods: {
      change(par) {
        console.log("The value is: " + par);
        //HERE I can't get "event.target"
      }
    }
};
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.4.0-beta.1/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <el-input @change="change" placeholder="Input something here"/>
  </template>
</div>
```

I know I can call different functions, and in each one I know who is the relative input, but I'd like to use a common one.

Following the stacktrace I saw in `element-ui.common.js` the code of event fire:

```
handleChange: function handleChange(event) {
  this.$emit('change', event.target.value);
},
```

And there `element` passes just the value to the event handler.
Anyway, any idea to get the `event.target`, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use @input.native

```js
var Main = {
    methods: {
      change(event) {
        console.log("The value is: " + event.target.value);
        //HERE I can't get "event.target"
      }
    }
};
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.4.0-beta.1/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <el-input @input.native="change" placeholder="Input something here"/>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are `:value` attribute in the field.

My `el-input` got a `:value` attribute, no matter what I type, the returned event always show the original value, not the new one (Ex: current value is "grea", then I type "t", and the `event.target.value` is "grea", instead of "great")

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Element UI just eats the event and returns only the value. What you could do instead of `@change(change)` is `@keyup.native(change)` and then your `par` parameter will be the event rather than just the value.