# How do I access the user selected text within an element ui input?

Tags: javascript, input, element-ui, textselection, selection-api

I want to access the text within an [ElInput](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input) component via Javascript in Electron. According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) it is impossible to access information within an html input or textfield via window.getSelection.

I unsuccessfully tried to access the selection with the proposed selectionStart

```
const input = document.getElementById("input")
alert(input.selectionStart.toString)
```

Given that this doesn't work, what do I have to do, to get the text in my selection within my [el-input](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input)?

Comment: Please see following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379408/575468

Comment: This seems to work for textboxes and input fields,  is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397146/2008111

Comment: @caramba : That example uses document.getElementById to get at a html element. It's unclear to me how to replace it in this context.

Comment: What is "Election"?

Answer (score 3):

```html
<input value="try to select some of the text" onclick="console.log(this.value.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd))"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this answer: [How to get selected text from textbox control with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript/32397146#32397146) you can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all `elements` you need. You can use `class names`, `ids` or `tag names` and so on. Then iterate over them with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and add the [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) you need. Inside the `forEach` loop you can do whatever you like with any given `element`

**UPDATE**
Unfortunately the first solution did not work in Firefox. (see further down) This solution should work in more browsers.

```js
var mySpecialSelect = function(element){
  element.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    let startPos = element.selectionStart;
    let endPos = element.selectionEnd;        
    let field_value = element.value;
    let selectedText = field_value.substring(startPos,endPos);

    if(selectedText.length <= 0) {
      return; // stop here if selection length is <= 0
    }
    
    // log the selection
    console.log(selectedText);
  
    // you can use "element" or "this" to do whatever like toggle a class name
    element.classList.toggle('used-this-element'); 
  });
};

var textAreaElements = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
[...textAreaElements].forEach(mySpecialSelect);

var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input');
[...inputElements].forEach(mySpecialSelect);
```

```css
textarea,
input {
  border: solid 2px gray;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.used-this-element {
    border: solid 2px orange;
}
```

```html
<textarea  rows="4" cols="50">Select some text from here and check the console</textarea>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">Another text Box, Select some text from here and check the console</textarea>

<input type="text" value="Select or change this value">
```

**First solution (hidden in the "Show code snippet")** unfortunately `window.getSelection()` did not work in Firefox. I'll keep this solution here just because maybe someday it will work and then this would be the nicer solution.

```js
var mySpecialSelect = function(element){
  element.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    if(window.getSelection().toString().length <= 0) {
      return; // stop here if selection length is <= 0
    }
    
    // log the selection
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
  
    // you can use "element" or "this" to do whatever like toggle a class name
    element.classList.toggle('used-this-element'); 
  });
};

var textAreaElements = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
[...textAreaElements].forEach(mySpecialSelect);

var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input');
[...inputElements].forEach(mySpecialSelect);
```

```css
textarea,
input {
  border: solid 2px gray;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.used-this-element {
    border: solid 2px orange;
}
```

```html
<textarea  rows="4" cols="50">Select some text from here and check the console</textarea>
<textarea  rows="4" cols="50">Another text Box, Select some text from here and check the console</textarea>

<input type="text" value="Select or change this value">
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that does anything helpful. If you run *Run code snipptet* it logs empty string whenever text gets selected. I don't care about the selection event but do care about the selection content.

Comment: @Christian in which browser are you? In google chrome, if I select text it logs the selection and adds/toggles an orange border on the selected box. Is that working for you? I've updated the answer with a .gif from what I see. I agree, inplementing a `return` if selection length is 0 should be made, and is done in 10sec but I didn't see it as part of the question

Comment: @Christian please have a look at the updated answer. Now it works also in Firefox. Please, if something is not working add more details like which browser you are using. We are here trying to help you, please help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this short video [image] I have made from the ELInput link you provided, the explanation in general is:

Without seeing your html is a bit hard, but I am guessing you don't even have an input with an id of 'input' which is what your javascript code is querying for:

`const input = document.getElementById("input")`

Looking at the html on the ElInput link you have provided, those inputs have a class of `el-input__inner`, you can select the input by class with

`const input = document.getElementsByClass("el-input__inner")`

but this will return an array of elements, you need to make sure you are selecting the one you need (you can select by Id if you have actually added an id tag to the input element, also this is the reason you see a `[1]` in the video, it is selecting the element in that position of the array).

from there you can select your text inside the input element, and from javascript get the range of the selection with: `input.selectionStart` and `input.selectionEnd`

Having those you can now get the substring with `input.value.substr(input.selectionStart, input.selectionEnd)` and from there do whatever you need with the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.native` event handlers as described in [Vue.js + Element UI: Get "event.target" at change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873386/vue-js-element-ui-get-event-target-at-change), and then `selectionStart/End` of the underlying HTML element will work:

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      input: 'Select something.'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dothing(event) {
      let elem=event.target;
      console.log(elem.value.substring(elem.selectionStart,elem.selectionEnd));
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<el-input v-model="input" @mouseup.native="dothing"></el-input>
</div>
```